# Volley requests stopped working for all my android apps

Tags: php, android, mysql, request, android-volley

I am using Volley requests to interract with my databases and everything was fine. Suddenly all my apps stopped working properly, even though I did not change anything in my PHP codes or I did not update my apps.

I checked if the PHP scripts are working and they are working well and they can interract with databases.

The weird thing is if I change my databases directly, the changes will be shown in the application after a random delay, like 15-20 minutes. The same if I insert something from my app to the database, the changes will be performed with a big delay.

I was using the deprecated version of Volley so I thought that might be the reason, I changed it and the issue is not fixed yet.

```
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

What else should I try? What can cause that kind of issue all of a sudden since my PHP scripts and databases are working well?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project or giving Android studio a restart!! `build -> Clean`

Comment: I did it already but it didn't work. The problem appeared with my published  and unpublished apps only the ones which they use Volley library, probably it has to do something with the cache managment of Volley.